# requestFullscreen not working properly in Samsung mobile default browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one unity game running in WebGL and I want it to run in fullscreen after button click.

It works on a laptop and on google chrome in Android mobile but it's not working properly on Samsung mobile default web browser.

```
function fullscreen(){
      $(".fullscreenDiv").fadeOut("1000");
      let elem = document.getElementById("webGL");
      if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      screen.orientation.lock('landscape');

    }
```

On google chrome game loads in full screen after running above method but on Samsung browser, it goes into the full screen but does not cover full screen and give blank black area on the right side of the content.

What can I do to fill the full screen on Samsung Browser?[image: Samsung browser output]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems it is Samsung browser or Android problem. Apps on Android has to be forced to use fullscreen: Settings > Display > Full screen apps. On my phone, only Chrome mobile was set to fullscreen by default, other apps was set to auto. I switched Samsung browser to full screen and now it can use whole screen as Chrome.

So the solution may be to inform a user how to activate true full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browsers don't support FullScreen APIs

http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Comment: Not quite correct. In the table you linked, Firefox for Android for example has fullscreen enabled. Chrome, Opera and Blackberry for Mobile seem to support it as well with a few exceptions.